# Firebase Authenticate Using Apple in Unity on Android without requiring login details each time

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication, persistence, sign-in-with-apple

I have followed the following guide to get *Sign in with Apple* functioning on Android using Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/apple

When a user first logs into my app with Sign in with Apple they will be required to enter their login details and authorize my app. However, it seems that if the app is closed and reopened they will also be required to reenter those details each time.

Other Auth providers I have integrated have supported a silent authorization method, checking if the user has already authorized the app on this device or have given access to a refresh token which can be stored and used later. How can I access either of these through Firebase's implementation?

Comment: To whoever comes along to just down vote, could you please consider dropping a link or a comment instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Auth allows an authorized session to persist on the Firebase side of things, without holding on to or reauthenticating with the other third party Auth providers. The key words to Google are "auth state persistence". Here's a link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/start